# Output key from array?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, yaml

How can I output the peoples names below? e.g. Martin and Tabitha?

```
people:
-  martin:
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - python
      - perl
      - pascal
-  tabitha:
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - lisp
      - fortran
      - erlang
```

Here's the loop:

```
{{#each people}}
    {{ this }}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I don't have JSON just this YAML

Comment: Kevin Kloet in handlebars syntax.

Comment: @KevinKloet what does that have to do with handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to be:

```
{{#each people}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This is what you get in the screen by doing that: `0: [object Object] 1: [object Object]`... Your are printing the key, but not the name as asked in the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can create a block helper `list` to iterate over `people` and use the current `index` as a private variable to obtain the name which is the first key in the object: `Object.keys(context[i])[0]`.

Code:

```js
var people = [{"martin": {"job": "Developer","skills": ["python","perl","pascal"]}}, {"tabitha": {"job": "Developer","skills": ["lisp","fortran","erlang"]}}];

// Register list helper
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function (context, options) {
  var out = '<ul>',
      data;

  if (options.data) {
    data = Handlebars.createFrame(options.data);
  }

  for (var i = 0, l = context.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (data) {
      data.index = Object.keys(context[i])[0];
    }

    out += '<li>' + options.fn(context[i], {
      data: data
    }) + '</li>';
  }

  out += '</ul>';
  return out;
});

// The main template
var main = Handlebars.compile($('#main').html());

// Register the list partial that 'main' uses
Handlebars.registerPartial('list', $('#list').html());

// Render the list
$('#output').html(main({
  people: people
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="list" type="x-handlebars-template">
  {{#list people}}
    {{@index}}
  {{/list}}
</script>

<script id="main" type="x-handlebars-template">  
  {{> list}}
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**Note**: I have converted the yaml to an array for the code example.